# FQL query get video with a particular tag

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using facebook php sdk for my application. Is it possible to get the videos which has a particular tag with fql?

My idea is:
people will upload a video on their wall. when uploading, the will use a tag (with '@' sign) to link up my application.

My application will fetch those videos which have that certain tag.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since you cannot search globally for videos and their tags (tags in video context are mostly poeple)

See the permissions from the join table [video_tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video_tag) (the same applies to `video`)

> To read video_tag you need
>
> - Any valid access_token for Page owned videos
> - user_videos permissions for all videos owned by the user (including nonpublic videos)
> - friend_videos permissions for videos owned by the user's friends
>     (including nonpublic videos that the friend has allowed the user to
>     view)

Unless you are friends with anyone who posts a video, I don't think there is a solution to what you try to do.